# How to get the sum of 2 datetimepicker and add or subtruct a decimal value on it on vb?

Tags: vb.net

this is MY CODe !!!!!

```
date1 = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTimePicker1.Value)
date2 = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTimePicker2.Value)
diff = date2.Subtract(date1)
Dim d As Double = 0.5


If Convert.ToInt32(diff.Days) >= 0 Then
    day.Text = Convert.ToInt32(diff.TotalDays)
    time.Text = Convert.ToInt32(diff.TotalHours)
End If

day.Text = Convert.ToInt32(diff.TotalDays)
time.Text = Convert.ToInt32(diff.TotalHours)



day.Visible = True
time.Visible = True
```

that is my code

Comment: too muddled, what's the matter? what does "the sum of 2 datetimepicker" stand for? put an example of what you want to do and your expected result ...

Comment: `2016-09-30 + 1999-12-24 = 42`

Comment: @Alex : that makes no sense, you can add a date to an integer or a time but not another date

Comment: `that makes no sense` that´s what I wanted to say in a more subtle manner ;) The question in its current state does not make sense and needs to be clarified by the PO.